# SSIS - Error ORA - 28040 No matching authentication

Tags: oracle, ssis, ado.net, oracle12c, msbi

I have developed SSIS package that connects to Oracle 12c. This package fails on my local machine but runs perfectly fine on our server.

The Oracle source is 12c and it's on a different server.

My local machine and my server (where the package runs successfully) has Oracle client installed.

Error on my local machine:

> Error: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {FAA372E9-C0AA-419F-9215-668FF9BD5A77} with the following error message: "ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
> "

I have verified the sqlnet file and ojdbc jar file.
It's as below:

*SQLNET.ora file:*

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
sqlnet.allowed_logon_version_server=8
```

ojdbc8.jar is present.

[image: ojdbc file]

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to run the package from my local and SSMS to run from my server.

Comment: ORA-28040 typically indicates that you are using  an outdated client library. But I have never used Ado.net or SSIS, so I don't know where you configure the correct client there (but I am sure the JDBC driver is not relevant)

Comment: have you tried ODBC connection instead of ADO.NET?. I have a recollection of a similar issue I had a few years ago and changing to ODBC did the trick.

Comment: The package works successfully on my server. Initially I was using ODBC when the Oracle source was 11g. In October last year it was moved to Oracle 12c and I had to struggle making my packagaes work that time. That is when I used ADO.net connection. However now while making some other changes to the package, it stopped working on my local. Though it works successfully on the server. So thought the issue was with the environment. @Jayvee

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for letting me know that jdbc driver isn't relevant here

Comment: @LearningPy , one more thing I can think of is adding sqlnet.allowed_logon_version_CLIENT=8 to SQLNET.ora

Comment: @Jayvee, thanks will try that